# Durandal null/empty route

Tags: javascript, durandal, durandal-2.0, durandal-navigation

I have a master/detail situation. I'd like to employ a child router so that I can (a) make full use of the history module and (b) trigger the entrance transition on only the child. Here's my setup:

### Shell.js

```
// configure the shell router
router.map([{ 
    ...
},{ 
    route: 'users*edit', 
    title: 'User List', 
    moduleId: 'viewmodels/users' 
}]).activate();
```

### Users.js

```
this.router = router
    .createChildRouter()
    .makeRelative({ fromParent: true })
    .map({ route: ':id', moduleId: 'viewmodels/edit' })
```

When I navigate to `#/users/5` it works brilliantly. However, when I navigate to `#/users`, as expected, it fires a route not found, cancels navigation, and returns me to `#/users/5`. How should I configure this to disable the child view when the route is not found? Ideally, I'd like to have something like this:

### Users.js

```
this.router = router
    .createChildRouter()
    .makeRelative({ fromParent: true })
    .map([ 
        { route: ':id', moduleId: 'viewmodels/edit' },
        { route: '', moduleId: null }
])
```

where the router will successfully navigate to the '' route but the null parameter will instruct it to simply empty the router binding handler.

Comment: You might want to check for `id` in `canActivate` and `return true;` if there's one and `return {redirect: 'emptyIdRoute'};` otherwise.

Comment: or, even easier would be to replace null in the second example with 'emptyIdRoute'. The problem is, I don't really want an empty view/model floating around. I'm looking for an instruction to tell the durandal router just to empty the router container. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not currently a feature of Durandal. I have added support for this kind of thing in a pull request, which you can find [here](https://github.com/BlueSpire/Durandal/pull/417), in case you would like to add support for null routes to your app.